# Show UIBarButtonItem just like Apple's iPad Mail App

Tags: objective-c

Apple's iPad **Mail** app has a few icons that appear *embedded* in the **setRightBarButtonItems** area of the **navigationItem** of the detail view of the split view controller:

[image]

How can I add icons to the navigationItem bar like this (I have the icons already).

My issue is that the UIBarButtonItem class reference doesn't seem to have an appropriate UIBarButtonItemStyle that allows for no border around the button.  I've tried configuring the UIBarButtonItem via initWithCustomView yet tapping the button doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Cheers

EDIT: I could use UIBarButtonItemStylePlain however it doesn't look 'embedded' like the apple buttons, which is the look I am after.

[image]

Comment: What is your problem with the default `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply.  I've edited the original post to show the result of UIBarButtonItemStylePlain.  It's not the look I'm trying to achieve unfortunately.

Comment: That looks like the bordered style, are you sure that it set up correctly? In some cases plain style is not supported.

Comment: It's possible that they are using it as a UINavBar, but hiding it and just putting in the buttons as normal UIButtons instead. You can set the navbarhidden property and do whatever you want. You have way more control that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out and can produce the following result:

[image]

Here is the code I use.  It could be optimised however is nice and repetitive for demonstration purposes:

```
- (void)setupNavigationItemButtons {

float buttonWidth = 60;
float buttonHeight = 40;

UIImage *imageA = [UIImage imageNamed:@"212-action2.png"]; 
UIImage *imageB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"];
UIImage *imageC = [UIImage imageNamed:@"122-stats.png"];

UIButton *buttonA = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
UIButton *buttonB = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
UIButton *buttonC = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];

[buttonA addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttonB addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomethingElse:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttonC addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomethingRandom:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[buttonA setImage:imageA forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonB setImage:imageB forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonC setImage:imageC forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonItemA = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonA];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItemB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonB];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItemC = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonC];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonItemA, buttonItemB, buttonItemC,nil]];
```

}